# Remote Command execution after scp transfer

Tags: linux, zip, scp

I have been having some trouble doing remote execution after data transfer.

Goal: SCP zipped data to a remote host then execute a remote command to unzip that file.I would prefer to do this in one command and only authenticate once. I need the solution to work in both PowerShell or Linux CLI.The remote host will always be linux but the source sending the file could be either Windows or Linux.

So far I have tried this but I get an error.

> scp file.zip user@server:/tmp >(cd /tmp && unzip)

Doing this command outputs the following error and also shows unzip usage to the prompt

> Error: /dev/fd/63: Not a directory

If I omit the the second command it copies as it should it just won't execute the second command successfully when stringed together.

Not sure what I'm missing or if there is a better alternative to accomplish the same task.

Comment: there seem to be a number of issues here. first, SCP will not give you a remote shell session, so you;ll need to login to the remote using ssh or similar. once you have established the ssh session you can run your cd and unzip. no idea what you are trying to do with the output redirection operator `>`. and you'll have to specify the file you want to unzip. also note, ssh client and scp client are not usually available in windows, so you;ll have to use tools like putty and winscp to execute on windows.

Comment: I was hoping there was some clever way to execute a command after transfering the data with one command. However, it looks like I may be stuck using two commands and authenticating twice.

Comment: there are certainly ways to handle the authentication issue, and there's no real drawback to using a script instead of a single line (though you probably could get it down to one multi-statement line without too much difficulty). https://linuxhint.com/script-ssh-login-with-passwords/